# QGIS error adding ArcGIS MapServers

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, addlayer

I'm trying to add an ArcGIS tile service in QGIS 3.16.10 via the 'Add ArcGIS Map Service Layer' tool

The service is:
https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/tileservices/Hosted/HistoricalImagery1943/MapServer

I can add the service, connect, select the layer ('Imagery') and a layer is added. However the layer is blank.

When I enter the layer Properties/Information, I note 'Data Type: Could not determine raster data type'

I can add WMS (through the WMS tool) from the same data supplier, and they operate fine. However testing other MapServer layers from the data supplier (through the Maps services tool) all appear empty.

I can't find any similar experiences online and unclear what the issue may be?